# Minimize reprojection error using fminunc in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have been given a dataset on which I have to run an optimalization function in order to find a set of parameters which gives the smallest reprojection error.

I have to use `fminunc()` in MATLAB. The minimization term is the following

[image: Minimization term]

`K` are the camera intrinsics, `P_j` is the camera pose, `p_i` is the feature location in 3D space and these 3 terms multiplied give the projection of the feature. `x_ij` is the 2D image of the feature. Subtracting the projection and the image gives the reprojection error.

Each camera pose only observes a certain amount of features so we can not calculate the reprojection error for each feature for each pose. Hence the `v_ij` variable which is a boolean value determining whether point `i` is visible in pose `j`. After taking the norm we then sum all the reprojection errors for each point in each pose which gives a total reprojection error. This error must be minimized.

The problem is that I can't wrap my head around on how to write this in a function which I can pass to `fminunc()`.

I wrote a function which calculates the reprojection error for a specific pose. I now need a way to do it for each pose and somehow optimize the error. This is where I get lost.

```
function error = reprojectenError(P,K,p,x,m)

% Get current pose
pose = P;

% Get the IDs for the features available for current pose
ids = m;

% Get available 3D features based on the IDs
feature_3d = p(:,ids);

% Get the projected features for the current pose
feature_2d = x;

% Normalize z row of projection to use x and y coordinates.
projection = K*pose*feature_3d;
projection_n = projection(1:2,:)./repmat(projection(3,:),2,1);

calc = projection_n - feature_2d;

% Calculate norm
error = sqrt(sum(calc.^2,1)).';
end
```

The code which loops over each pose

```
options = optimoptions('fminunc','MaxFunEvals',5000);

for k = 1:4
    e = fminunc(@reprojectenError,P{k},options,K,p,x{k},m{k})
    err_min = reprojectenError(e,K,p,x{k},m{k})
end
```

Variable assignment

```
P = bad.camera_poses;
K = bad.camera_intrinsics;
p = bad.feature_points_3d; % actual location of feature
x = bad.feature_locations; % projected feature
m = bad.feature_ids; % mapping table
```

Comment: What parameters do you want to optimize?

Comment: Can you give some toy data to play with?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis The data is a struct and the only way to share it is like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/igewchlaj4qo23z/bundle_adjust_data_v2_noisy.mat?dl=0. I have updated the question for variable assignment

Comment: @dasdingonesin the parameters that have to be optimized is `P_j` whilst trying to minimize the total reprojection error